# Limit number of goroutine picking task in loop

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am running a loop - 24 times which calls a downstream that is not able to handle all the work supplied concurrently by the go-routines spawned, I want to limit that such that only a specific number (3 or 4) of go-routine gets executed.
Sample code looks like below, if anyone can point me to the right pattern to fulfil this would be a great help

```
for i:=0; i<24; i++ {
   go callSomeDownStream()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the channel of empty structs to control the number of concurrent worker goroutines

```golang
const MAX_CONCURRENT_JOBS = 3

func main() {
    waitChan := make(chan struct{}, MAX_CONCURRENT_JOBS)

    for i:=0; i < 24; i++ {
        waitChan <- struct{}{}
        go func() {
            callSomeDownStream()
            <-waitChan
        }()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arpit, note that basically this is a [counting semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) in disguise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
func callSomeDownStream(wg *sync.WaitGroup, queue chan struct{}) {
    defer func() {
        <-queue
        wg.Done()
    }()
    // do something
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    queue := make(chan struct{}, 3)
    for i := 0; i < 24; i++ {
        queue <- struct{}{}
        wg.Add(1)
        go callSomeDownStream(&wg, queue)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(queue)
}
```

Comment: `<-queue`should before `wg.Done()`,otherwise chan maybe leak

Comment: @Para Do you mean the order of (queue<-,wg.Add) and (<-queue,wg.Done) should be kept? I think it's a good habit. But it doesn't seem like there will be a leak in this scenario?

Comment: thank you it does work but accepted answer is much simpler for the problem